Can I draw a full body, With minimal detail, and without any facial features?
I am looking to create work for extra money. By selling some of my commission, I was wondering if I could sell drawings with anatomy. Specifically, if I can draw bodies, with little detail (obviously no nude) and still draw a few details of the face. For example, a body with eyes and a nose or a body with eyes and a mouth.
